# Passing very large objects over XML-RPC in Python

Tags: python, json, xml-rpc

I've been messing around with a few personal projects, and have found the need to offload the processing of a large amount of data to more beefy, dedicated servers. I tend to do this over XML-RPC in Python, and have made some interesting observations, and wanted to both share, and see if anybody knows of a better or more efficient way of doing this.

So, let's say I need to send a large amount of data over XML-RPC in Python. What's the fastest way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I started doing some experimenting with the XML-RPC module, as there isn't much about it online. Initially, to handle my data (~15 megabytes), I was simply passing a dictionary object to the XML-RPC method on the client side. This was very slow, on both the server and client side- each took a few minutes *just* to encode/decode the data! I assume (but am not sure) that this is an issue with having to encode a lot of data in XML.

However, after some fiddling around, I tried serializing the dictionary as a JSON object with `json.dumps` on the client end and loading it with `json.loads` on the server side, which to my surprise, ended up being *many* times faster.

> **Warning: Pure Speculation!**
>
> I suspect that the XML encoding may be so much slower than JSON encoding because `json.dumps` is written in CPython, but I do not know if Python's XML encoding is written in CPython. I ran in to a similar issue using `json.dumps` vs `json.dump` in a previous project: the latter is many times slower because it is written in pure Python; as opposed to being written in CPython (in the words of the Python bug report, "json.dump doesn't use the C accelerations": https://bugs.python.org/msg137170).

I *could* theoretically upload the serialized JSON string (or pickled dict object, but this strikes me as a bad idea) to cloud storage, such as AWS S3, and then pull it on the server end, but I feel like I might as well just send the data directly from one machine to the other at that point.

I'm going to experiment with doing some gzip compression on the serialized JSON string to hopefully cut down on network bandwidth being a bottleneck, as I eventually plan on being able to handle gigabytes of data over RPC. I'll post my results here.

I thought this was interesting, and I'm wondering if anybody has run in to this issue before, and how they've went about it. I haven't been able to find much online. Cheers!